# Update a document and create a field that is an array of all the objects with the same id in the collection MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection with documents organized like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ea084718a475ee5faaaf3b7"),
        "vehicleid" : 32040,
        "date" : ISODate("2018-02-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "points" : {
                "direction" : 135,
                "latitude" : -3.744851,
                "longitude" : -38.545571,
                "odometer" : 55697826,
                "routecode" : 0,
                "speed" : 3,
                "deviceid" : 134680,
                "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T02:59:59Z")
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ea084718a475ee5faaaf3b8"),
        "vehicleid" : 32040,
        "date" : ISODate("2018-02-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "points" : {
                "direction" : 270,
                "latitude" : -3.840556,
                "longitude" : -38.4954,
                "odometer" : 24358799,
                "routecode" : 0,
                "speed" : 0,
                "deviceid" : 97878,
                "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T02:59:19Z")
        }
}
```

I need a way to update the collection by creating a new "points" field that will be an array of all "points" objects in all documents with the same "vehicleid" and "date", like:

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ea084718a475ee5faaaf3b8"),
            "vehicleid" : 32040,
            "date" : ISODate("2018-02-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "points" : [{
                    "direction" : 270,
                    "latitude" : -3.840556,
                    "longitude" : -38.4954,
                    "odometer" : 24358799,
                    "routecode" : 0,
                    "speed" : 0,
                    "deviceid" : 97878,
                    "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T02:59:19Z")
            },
                   {
                    "direction" : 135,
                    "latitude" : -3.744851,
                    "longitude" : -38.545571,
                    "odometer" : 55697826,
                    "routecode" : 0,
                    "speed" : 3,
                    "deviceid" : 134680,
                    "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T02:59:59Z")
                                                                        }]
    }
```

**Any ideas???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `$out` in MongoDB

Here is shell query for same:

I'm keeping the name of the second collection different if you want to update the same collection you can keep the name of collection same.

**NOTE** `$out` will replace all the documents already present in your collection with the output of your aggregation till the last stage. So, you better handle it carefully.

```
db.first_collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project:{
      "_id":0
    }
  },
  {
    $group:{
      "_id":{
        "vehicleid":"$vehicleid",
        "date":"$date"
      },
      "date":{
        $first:"$date"
      },
      "vehicleid":{
        $first:"$vehicleid"
      },
      "points":{
        $push:"$points"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      "_id":0
    }
  },
  {
    $out:"second_collection"
  }
])
```

For more about `$out` read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/).

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)