# $out comand on pymongo is creating an empty collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have this following python code:

```
import pymongo

connection_string = 'mongodb://localhost'
connection = pymongo.MongoClient(connection_string)
database = connection.solutions
pipe = [
        {
    "$match": {
      "metrictimestamp": {"$gte": "2018-02-01T00:00:00.000+00:00", "$lte": "2018-02-01T23:59:59.000+00:00"}
    }
         },
        {"$out": "day"}
              
      ]

database.solution3.aggregate(pipe,allowDiskUse=True)
```

**But the "day" collection is empty, am i doing anything wrong?**

*The query is to create a collection with de documents of a especific day*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing string comparison based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61415530/update-a-document-and-create-a-field-that-is-an-array-of-all-the-objects-with-th)

If field `metricTimestamp` is integer or long, use `new Date("2018-02-01T00:00:00Z").getTime()`. Similarly on the other field.

If field is of type `date`, use `new Date()` variation without time method.

If field is of type string, use `$dateFromString`

Use this:

```
{
    "$match": {
      "metrictimestamp": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2018-02-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "$lte": ISODate("2018-02-01T23:59:59Z")
      }
    }
  }
```

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fQF17xC4U9y)

Comment: I used this: "$gte": "new Date(2018-02-01T00:00:00)", the new Date without the quotes points an error, but this way the collection still is empty

Comment: You have to have quotes for date value I.e `new Date("Here Your Date")` but not as ` "new Date()"`

Comment: i tried exactly this way, pointed an error on the "Date"

Comment: pipe = [
        {
    "$match": {
      "metrictimestamp": {"$gte": new Date("2018-02-01T00:00:00"), "$lte": new Date("2018-02-01T23:59:59")}
    }
         },
        {
          "$out": "day"
          }
              
      ]

Comment: Could you add a document which should be part of the result?

Comment: {"_id":{"$oid":""},"direction":0,"metrictimestamp":{"$date":"2018-02-01T02:59:55.000Z"},"odometer":19030291,"routecode":0,"speed":0,"deviceid":8155064,"vehicleid":34489,"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-3.878595,-38.533493]}}

Comment: You have an object. Then you need to use `metricTimestamp.date`.Bur why do you have $date as the field name

Comment: the mongo created this object automaticaly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219550/discussion-between-gibbs-and-arturbraga).